# Segmentation fault on vector of objects

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management

I'm currently trying to programm a neural network header file to train neural networks, the NN.h file contains all the neural network stuff.
NN.h also includes another header file I have programmed myself, named Matrix.h which contains a class to handle all the matrix stuff with memory management.

The memory management works fine when I don't use vectors for the Matrix objects but as soon as I use them with vectors I get Segmentation fault error.

This is the program output:

```
Matrix destruction started
0 0 0 
Matrix destruction started
0 0 0 
Matrix destruction started
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
Matrix destruction started
2 2 2 
Matrix destruction started
10 10 10 
Matrix destruction started
9 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

NN.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrix.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
class NN{
  private:
    std::vector<int> info;
    std::vector<Matrix<double> > layer;
    std::vector<Matrix<double> > weights;
    std::vector<Matrix<double> > bias;
    std::vector<Matrix<double> > result;
    std::vector<Matrix<double> > temp;
    double learnigRate;
public:
    NN(std::vector<int> &layers){
        info = layers;
        layer.reserve(layers.size());
        for (size_t i = 0;i < layers.size();i++){
            layer.push_back(Matrix<double> (layers[i],1,0));
        }
        weights.reserve(layers.size()-1);
        for (size_t i = 0;i < (layers.size()-1);i++){
            weights.push_back(Matrix<double> (layers[i],layers[i+1],0));
        }
        bias.reserve(layer.size()-1);
        for (size_t i= 0; i < (layers.size()-1);i++){
            bias.push_back(Matrix<double> (layers[i+1],1,2));
        }
        result.push_back(Matrix<double> (layers[layers.size()-1],1,10));

        temp.push_back(Matrix<double> (1,1,9));
    }
    ~NN(){
        for (size_t i = 0;i < info.size();i++){
            delete &layer[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = 0;i < (info.size()-1);i++){
            delete &weights[i];
        }
        for (size_t i= 0; i < (info.size()-1);i++){
            delete &bias[i];
        }
        delete &result[0];
        delete &temp[0];
    }
};
```

Matrix.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
template <class W> class Matrix{
private:
    int state = 0;
    int printError(Matrix<W> &a){
        if(state != 0 && a.state != 0){
            std::cerr <<"matrix.h error : " << "Both matrices not correctly initialized!" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if(state != 0){
            std::cerr <<"matrix.h error : " << "Matrix 1 not correctly initialized!" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if(a.state != 0){
            std::cerr <<"matrix.h error : " << "Matrix 2 not correctly initialized!" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
public:
W ** matrix;
int size_x,size_y;
template <typename X> Matrix(int size_tx,int size_ty,X value){
  W temp = (W) value;
  size_x = size_tx;
  size_y = size_ty;
  int x = 0;
  try{
   matrix = new W*[size_y];
  }
  catch(const std::bad_alloc&)
  {
   std::cerr << "Could not allocate matrix: bad_alloc()" << std::endl;
   state = 1;
   return;
  }
  try{
  for(x = 0; x < size_y;x++){
    matrix[x] = new W[size_x];
  }
  }
  catch (const std::bad_alloc&)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not allocate matrix: bad_alloc()" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < x-1;i++){
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    state = 1;
    return;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < size_y; i++){
    for(int j = 0;j< size_x;j++){
        matrix[i][j] = temp;
    }
  }
  state = 0;
}
~Matrix(){
  if (state == 0)
    freeMatrix();
  }
int freeMatrix(){
    std::cout << "Matrix destruction started" << std::endl;
    printMatrix();
    for(int i = 0; i < size_y;i++){
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;
    return 0;
}
int printMatrix(){
  for(int i = 0; i < size_y; i++){
    for(int j = 0;j< size_x;j++){
      std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
return 0;
}
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "matrix.h"
#include "NN.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<int> net (3);
  net = {3,3};
  NN n(net);
  return 0;
}
```

These are shortened versions of my code, but the relevant parts should still be there.

There is still the same error when I delete the destructor of the NN class,
however when I remove the Matrix destructor there is not error, but I would like to solve the problem with a clean solution that respects memory management.

If you need more information feel free to ask me.

Comment: Where did it get to when you ran it in a debugger?

Comment: I have stepped through the code with gdb, the segmentation error appears in `freeMatrix()` at `delete [] matrix[i];`

Comment: When I delete the NN destructor there is a double free or corruption error instead of segmentation fault!

Comment: Obviously, it fails there because you should not call `delete` on that object as it was not allocated on the heap (i.e. `new` was not used to create that object).

Comment: Ok, but I still get Segmentation fault when I delete the NN destructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, `~NN()` implementation is wrong. It makes no sense to delete an object that is not allocated dynamically. When items are added, objects (on stack) are pushed back.

Given that you use vector in `NN`, why would you not do so for `Matrix` too? It would greatly simplify the code, help prevent memory leaks and make the code stronger and safer...

Catching exception in a constructor and setting a flag to indicate a failure is a very bad idea. **In fact, exceptions were added to the language to avoid that pattern among other things.** It is know to be bad practice since almost 20 years if not more...

Another thing is that you copy `Matrix` object without having defined the copy constructor (nor the assignment operator) and assuming you are using C++ 11, you should also provide move constructor and assignment.

Another thing you should do is to always put the matching header file first in the include list of a given source (only after precompiled headers if applicable). That way, it help ensure that any header file compile by itself.

I would recommend you to read good books on C++ like **Exceptional C++**. There is also a lot of information available on the web. For example, you should learn the rule of 5 among other (for ex. : http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/rule-of-five.html or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

In modern C++, it is recommended to avoid explicit memory management. You should use classes like 'std::vector', 'std::unique_ptr`,`std::shared_ptr` among other to help you write maintainable exception-safe code that works as intended.

If you want to do C++, then you have to put a lot of effort into learning. Otherwise, switch to an easier language like C# or Swift...